# Crystal Report 2008 display format

Tags: crystal-reports

currently, i working on Crystal report 2008 use cross tab for design report. 
the report format display like as
[image]

but I want the display as 
Example:
[image]

How I get display like this? Kindly help me

Thank you
-Praba

Comment: i couldn't seen your Jan Feb ....  from above where is it came from

Comment: Sorry.. The sample i just created in in excel format. It should be 1, 2 ,3 and etc. the main part i needed how to separate every month value and total. Normally, the total will show end of every row. how i can separate row value first and then the total of each row?